# High frequency voltage to current

Tags: current-source, high-frequency

I have a signal oscillating at tens or hundreds of MHz (up to 200 MHz expected), with 2.5 V mean and approx 200 mV peak to peak. I'd like to produce a current proportional to this signal at approx 40-50 mA mean to drive an LED.

I'm thinking about using this kind of floating load voltage to current circuit:

[image]

Is this kind of circuit suitable for high frequency signal? If yes, does the AD8000 opamp would be suitable? If not, which kind of (simple) circuit should I use (I'm running single supply)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: At frequencies like that, you're going to need to look at current-feedback amplifiers, not conventional op amps.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem: you are asking about incomplete (and potentially infeasible) proposed solution Y to problem X.  Please ask about problem X instead. To be specific, what is infeasible here is current modulation of an LED at such frequencies; as far as I know, LEDs drop off around 10MHz in terms of electrical and optical (modulation) bandwidth. You will need a wholly different solution to obtain 200MHz -- or a wholly different underlying requirement to use less bandwidth.

Comment: @TimWilliams is it still true for laser diode ?

Comment: Depends on the laser diode; typically a laser diode driver circuit would be used, and/or a coupling network. Ideal sources (whether CV or CC) aren't meaningful at such frequencies, and bandwidth, device characteristics, and the network between amplifier and device, are the meaningful topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an amplifier below. Use HF transistor, more powerful.
The load is R1.
The input voltage vs. R1 current dependency is inverted, i.e. input voltage up causes R1 current down.

[image: schematic]

Top is input voltage, below is R1 current.
The phase is shifted probably because of slow transistor.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, what is the relation between V1 and the current in the R1 load resistor ? How can I change the factor between V1 and the current ? Also, what happens if I have a voltage drop instead R1, as I will place an LED instead ?